# KO Mapping issue with child objects

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I get the following data from the server:

```
var data =   [{ id: 0, child: { prop1 : 'a', prop2 : 'b' } }   //Child object has data
             ,{ id: 0, child: null } ];    // Child object is null
```

I'm having some issues after I map the data using the knockout mapping plugin. The issue is that the inner `child` object is not of the same type.

After executing this:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel.data);
```

I get that the first object has a `child` property of type `Object` with the data. However the second object has a property `child` of type `Observable` that when it's unwrapped returns null.

How can I make that in both cases the objects have the same type even one has value and the other one is null. Changing the way the server behaves is not an option. I expect having `Object` and `null` or both `Observables`.

JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tupB8/1/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [`create` option](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#customizing_object_construction_using_create) to tell the mapping plugin how it should map your `child` property.

So if you want to have having `Object` and `null` you need to return `null` when your child property is `null`:

```
var mappingOptions = {
    child: {
        create: function(options) {
            if (!options.data)
                return null;
            return ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
        }
    }
}

ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions, viewModel.data);
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wEfWR/).

Or if you want them both `Observables`:

```
var mappingOptions = {
    child: {
        create: function(options) {
            return ko.observable(ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data));
        }
    }
}

ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions, viewModel.data);
```

Comment: always test the options.data for null value and then return empty ko.observable()

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the solution is mapping options, but make sure to always **test the options.data for null value** and then return empty ko.observable(), otherwise you are going to have a lot of trouble with binding! I spent a lot of time on finding that.

```
var mappingOptions = {
    child: {
        create: function (options) {
            return options.data != null ? ko.observable(ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data)) : ko.observable();
        }
    }
}
```