# knockout.mapping - convert whole object included nested objects to knockout.observable

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am using knockout.mapping to convert my javascript object into a knockout observable. Inside this javascript object is a nested object and this nested object is being converted but it is in the wrong place. So when my view tries to bind the data it can't because the mapping has moved the nested object to the root.

**JSON data**

```
[
    {
        "brandName": "Knockando Single Malt Whisky",
        "categoryDescription": "Alcohol - Whisky & Bourbon",
        "dateAmended": "2008-01-28T10:05:00.000Z",
        "defaultSearchName1": "KnockandoSingleMaltWhisky",
        "defaultSearchName2": "Knockando Single Malt Whisky",
        "advertiser": {
            "activities": "Motor dealers",
            "additionalInfo": "",
            "advertiserName": "Parks of Hamilton Ltd",
            "alfRank": 3311,
            "cinemaRank": 286,
            "directMailRank": 1291,
            "internetRank": 1988,
            "notes": "Trade as Parks Motor Group.\nAlternative email: coachhire@park.uk.com, admin@park-uk.com, Info@park.uk.com.",
            "numberOfEmployees": 1000,
            "outdoorRank": 1426,
            "pressRank": 5159,
            "radioRank": 675,
            "tVRank": 1810
        }
    },
    {
        "brandName": "Tesco Petrol/Diesel Fuel",
        "categoryDescription": "Petrol & Service Stations",
        "dateAmended": "2013-07-10T15:17:00.000Z",
        "defaultSearchName1": "TescoPetrol/DieselFuel",
        "defaultSearchName2": "Tesco Petrol/Diesel Fuel",
        "advertiser": {
            "activities": "Furnitures",
            "additionalInfo": "",
            "advertiserName": "Pine & Things Ltd",
            "alfRank": 4570,
            "cinemaRank": 286,
            "directMailRank": 1291,
            "internetRank": 1988,
            "notes": "Trade as P&T.\nAlternative email: info@pineandthings.co.uk.",
            "numberOfEmployees": 25,
            "outdoorRank": 1426,
            "pressRank": 2851,
            "radioRank": 2449,
            "tVRank": 1810
        }
    },
    {
        "brandName": "Tesco Electrical Products",
        "categoryDescription": "Supermarkets & Multiple Retailers",
        "dateAmended": "2013-07-10T15:52:00.000Z",
        "defaultSearchName1": "TescoElectricalProducts",
        "defaultSearchName2": "Tesco Electrical Products",
        "advertiser": {
            "activities": "Bridalwear",
            "additionalInfo": "",
            "advertiserName": "Phil Collins Bridal Collection Ltd",
            "alfRank": 4094,
            "cinemaRank": 286,
            "directMailRank": 1291,
            "internetRank": 1988,
            "notes": "Alternative email: enquiries@philcollinsbridal.co.uk, pcbridal@aol.com.",
            "numberOfEmployees": 30,
            "outdoorRank": 1426,
            "pressRank": 2487,
            "radioRank": 2449,
            "tVRank": 1810
        }
    },
    {
        "brandName": "Tesco Bank Insurance Ranges",
        "categoryDescription": "Insurance Ranges",
        "dateAmended": "2012-01-05T12:30:00.000Z",
        "defaultSearchName1": "TescoBankInsuranceRanges",
        "defaultSearchName2": "Tesco Bank Insurance Ranges",
        "advertiser": {
            "activities": "Nutition supplements",
            "additionalInfo": "",
            "advertiserName": "PhD Nutrition Ltd",
            "alfRank": 4107,
            "cinemaRank": 286,
            "directMailRank": 1291,
            "internetRank": 1988,
            "notes": "Alternative email: info@phd-supplements.com.\nThere is no alternative head office landline number.",
            "numberOfEmployees": 30,
            "outdoorRank": 1426,
            "pressRank": 2500,
            "radioRank": 2449,
            "tVRank": 1810
        }
    },
    {
        "brandName": "Tesco Clubcard",
        "categoryDescription": "Loyalty & Incentive Schemes",
        "dateAmended": "2008-03-26T14:05:00.000Z",
        "defaultSearchName1": "TescoClubcard",
        "defaultSearchName2": "Tesco Clubcard",
        "advertiser": {
            "activities": "",
            "additionalInfo": "",
            "advertiserName": "British Regional Airlines Group PLC",
            "alfRank": 6031,
            "cinemaRank": 286,
            "directMailRank": 1291,
            "internetRank": 1988,
            "notes": "",
            "numberOfEmployees": 0,
            "outdoorRank": 1426,
            "pressRank": 5159,
            "radioRank": 2449,
            "tVRank": 1810
        }
    },
    {
        "brandName": "Royal Mail Corporate",
        "categoryDescription": "Public Services - Corporate",
        "dateAmended": "2010-06-04T11:45:00.000Z",
        "defaultSearchName1": "RoyalMailCorporate",
        "defaultSearchName2": "Royal Mail Corporate",
        "advertiser": {
            "activities": "",
            "additionalInfo": "",
            "advertiserName": "Yorkshire Power Group Ltd",
            "alfRank": 6031,
            "cinemaRank": 286,
            "directMailRank": 1291,
            "internetRank": 1988,
            "notes": "",
            "numberOfEmployees": 0,
            "outdoorRank": 1426,
            "pressRank": 5159,
            "radioRank": 2449,
            "tVRank": 1810
        }
    },
    {
        "brandName": "E.ON Surf & Save ISP",
        "categoryDescription": "Telecom - Internet Service Providers",
        "dateAmended": "2007-11-23T12:25:00.000Z",
        "defaultSearchName1": "E.ONSurf&SaveISP",
        "defaultSearchName2": "E.ON Surf & Save ISP",
        "advertiser": {
            "activities": "",
            "additionalInfo": "",
            "advertiserName": "Stagecoach Ltd",
            "alfRank": 6031,
            "cinemaRank": 286,
            "directMailRank": 1291,
            "internetRank": 1988,
            "notes": "",
            "numberOfEmployees": 0,
            "outdoorRank": 1426,
            "pressRank": 5159,
            "radioRank": 2449,
            "tVRank": 1810
        }
    }
]
```

**Javascript**

```
 // Get JSON from local storage and convert to js object
 var objBrands = new Object(ko.mapping.fromJSON(localStorage.getItem('Brands')));

 // Convert from object to observable
 brands = ko.mapping.fromJS(objBrands)
```

**My object with data before being converted to observable**

[image]

**After conversion**

[image]

In screenshot two - advertiser is in the wrong place. I want it inside [0] but the ko.mapping parsed my object and put it there.

Comment: Could you write an explanation of what the problem is, what you have tried, etc...?

Comment: @PWKad Sure. I will update my question.

Comment: @PWKad Hey I explained it the best I can. If you look at my screenshots you can see where advertiser is within the object. After using ko.mapping it is in the wrong place.

Comment: So it doesn't make any sense to me, it IS a nested observable inside of [0], it is just in a different order?  If you were to call whatever the name of your observableArray is like this myArray()[0].advertisers() you would get a list of the advertisers, at least how I see it.  If you get an object is not a function error that means you are mapping the child properties properly, but with your code as it is I can't tell that --- you aren't mapping the child objects, see the link below

Comment: possible duplicate of [KO Mapping issue with child objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654663/ko-mapping-issue-with-child-objects)

Comment: i understand what you're trying to accomplish...you've got things a little too generic for mapping to work as you expect it to and need to define the mapping...otherwise it just skims over the top and gives you anonymous object. Control is the key...

Answer (score 8):

Here's your banana for the day.

There are a couple things your could do, but i'm going to point you to the direction of using the ko.mapping plugin. Here's a fiddle I drew up using your situation as an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/beauxjames/ps75V/

First thing you'll see with your data, I did add a little json object value to start as well as loaded it into a local variable ::

```
var rawData = { "brand": [
{...} ]};
```

Next, we've got jQuery, knockout.js, and knockout.mapping.js aboard.

Then, note the function types ::

```
var BrandsViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, brandMapping, self);
}

var AdvertiserViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
}
```

Now, inside of each there is a declaration for ko.mapping.fromJS()...which has a detailed explanation here :: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Then the mapping itself ::

```
var brandMapping = {
    'brands': {
        create: function (options) {
            if (options.data != null) return new BrandsViewModel(options.data);
        }
    },
    'advertiser': {
        create: function (options) {
            if (options.data != null) return new AdvertiserViewModel(options.data);
        }
    }
}
```

and then...the business end ::

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var viewModel = new BrandsViewModel(rawData);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('mylist'));
});
```

As you see...mapping these complex objects over to observables is really a snap with this plugin. Everything is tied up and you can push this to any kind of editable environment and go nuts...everything is there and you can extend your models right from within the declarations of the XXXViewModel and each instance of the object will just get smarter and smarter.

Hope this helped!