# What should you do in update callback of knockout.mapping in case options.data is null?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

This is 1 step further than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654663/ko-mapping-issue-with-child-objects) question.

I have a view model with nullable child property, like in before-mentioned question

```
var data =   [{ id: 0, child: { prop1 : 'a', prop2 : 'b' } }   //Child object has data
             ,{ id: 0, child: null } ];    // Child object is null
```

Now I want to use update callback of mapping plugin, and do this as follows:

```
var mappingOptions = {
    child: {
        create: function(options) {
            if (!options.data)
                return null;
            return ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
        }, 
        update: function(options) {
            if (!options.data)
                return null;

            // some update logic...

            return options.target; // this is also null in case options.data is null
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when the options.data is null, I get an error in console "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function", pointing to this code in mapping plugin:

```
...    
if (hasUpdateCallback()) {
    mappedRootObject(updateCallback(mappedRootObject));
}
...
```

where mappedRootObject is undefined.

So what should I return from update callback in case options.data is null?

[JSFiddle Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/wEfWR/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in case someone else will face the same issue, I've just updated ko.mapping plugin javascript as follows:

```
...    
if (hasUpdateCallback() && mappedRootObject) {
    mappedRootObject(updateCallback(mappedRootObject));
}
...
```

So, I check for existense of mappedRootObject before updating it. Although it worked fine, I've figured out a way, how to avoid update callback in my project at all, so this fix became useless to me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

For one, you never ran ko.applyBindings on your model.

http://jsfiddle.net/wEfWR/3/

```
ko.applyBindings(ko.mapping.fromJS(data))
```

Secondly, you're viewmodel object is not a function...nor is it really necessary.

New fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wEfWR/5/

Your 'child' object doesn't contain the data for child doesn't contain the child itself, so you need to make the update for your 'id' object instead.

```
update: function(options) {
    console.log(options);
    return options.data;
},
'child': {
    create: function(options) {
        if (!options.data)
            return null;
        return ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! There is no markup in my demo, so nothing to bind to. As for view model - it could be any object, right. Your demo doesn't include update - I've changed it http://jsfiddle.net/wEfWR/4/, same error appears.

Comment: Updated answer with new fiddle

Comment: I need to run update callback for each child object, that's why I placed it under 'child' mapping. In your updated answer update callback runs for main object, which makes it quite hard to work with 'child' objects - I have to manually check all child objects, find their pairs in existing view model (that is being updated) using a key callback (not specified in sample, but used in my project) - that's why I use ko.mapping, so it would do all this for me.

Comment: Be more specific about your 'key callback' && 'update callback'. Are you just talking about subscriptions to the 'child' object of every 'id' object?